# What is the chance that a chest spawns in fortnite BR?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Title says it all - looking for the spawn rate of chests. Not the contents, the chest itself.

Comment: There isnt a  spawn rate of chests . Like per example you wont see a chest randomly anywhere in the middle of nowhere. There are specific chest spawn location that are random if they appear or not. Sometimes I get 3 chests in one house, sometimes none. There is no spawn rate of chests

Comment: I understand that chests have spawn locations, and that within those locations they either spawn or they don’t. I’m asking what the chances are that they do spawn. There is a spawn rate for chests.

Comment: If there is a spawn rate of chests, It would be impossible to figure out beacuse we would have to basically hack the game to take a look. Also, even If we didint have too, not many plp on the web wanna try it. The only way we would know is if epic games stated somewhere. Unless your wondering about loot spawn rate in chests, this answer may be unsloved for some time or forever.

Comment: @GamerM, "hacking the game" is normally called data mining, and a lot of that has been done [here](https://db.fortnitetracker.com/loot). Even without data mining, we could get a close approximation by checking whether or not a chest spawned in a couple hundred different games. Number of spawns / number of games = spawn rate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific spawn rate, however from experience I'm pretty sure there is a 60% spawn rate.